# How to continue with merged Flowable of InputStreams if one is closed, RxJava 2.x

Tags: java, java-8, inputstream, rx-java2

I am new to RxJava2 and am not sure if I'm using it correctly.

I have a couple of InputStreams that are reading data from a TCP stream, and am reading data into a `byte[]`. I am then, taking the `byte[]` and creating a `Flowable` for each `InputStream` and merging the individual `Flowable` into one.

I would like to be able to close 1 `InputStream` but still have the merged `Flowable` continue reading from the non-closed `InputStream`.

Currently, I have it reading from 2 InputStreams correctly but when I call `close`, it results in an exception, `java.net.SocketException: Socket closed` being thrown.

My question is, how do I properly close the InputStream or Flowable so that I can continue to read from the other InputStream in the mean time.

```
InputStream inputStream = response.body().asInputStream();
InputStream inputStream2 = response2.body().asInputStream();

Flowable<byte[]> flowable = Bytes.from(inputStream)
                                 .distinct();

Flowable<byte[]> flowable2 = Bytes.from(inputStream2)
                                  .distinct();

Flowable.merge(flowable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()),
               flowable2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()))
        .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Data: " + new String(s)),
           e -> System.out.println("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage() + " : " + e.getMessage()),
           () -> System.out.println("Complete!"));

//Calling this results in an exception being thrown.
inputSteam2.close();
```

Stack trace:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
  at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.innerError(FlowableFlatMap.java:604)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$InnerSubscriber.onError(FlowableFlatMap.java:665)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onError(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:102)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableGenerate$GeneratorSubscription.onError(FlowableGenerate.java:189)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableGenerate$GeneratorSubscription.request(FlowableGenerate.java:114)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.requestUpstream(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:133)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:90)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableGenerate.subscribeActual(FlowableGenerate.java:52)
  at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12986)
  at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12932)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
  at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
  at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
  at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:238)
  at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:45)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$UnknownLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:476)
  at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:386)
  at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
  at com.github.davidmoten.rx2.Bytes$1.accept(Bytes.java:47)
  at com.github.davidmoten.rx2.Bytes$1.accept(Bytes.java:43)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableInternalHelper$SimpleGenerator.apply(FlowableInternalHelper.java:44)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableInternalHelper$SimpleGenerator.apply(FlowableInternalHelper.java:35)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableGenerate$GeneratorSubscription.request(FlowableGenerate.java:109)
  ... 14 more
Exception in thread "RxNewThreadScheduler-3" io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
  at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.innerError(FlowableFlatMap.java:604)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$InnerSubscriber.onError(FlowableFlatMap.java:665)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onError(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:102)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableGenerate$GeneratorSubscription.onError(FlowableGenerate.java:189)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableGenerate$GeneratorSubscription.request(FlowableGenerate.java:114)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.requestUpstream(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:133)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:90)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableGenerate.subscribeActual(FlowableGenerate.java:52)
  at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12986)
  at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12932)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: How is `Bytes.from` implemented? Have you tried with `mergeDelayError`?

Comment: I haven't seen mergeDelayError yet, I'll look into that. `Bytes.from` is from another another [library](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava2-extras/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/davidmoten/rx2/Bytes.java#L42) which generates a flowable by checking if the stream has ended yet or not.

Comment: After reading about `mergeDelayError`, I don't think I want that because when I close an inputStream, that exception would continue to exist until some unknown period of time that the other InputStreams are open for.

Comment: Then you need a Bytes.from that suppresses the close exception. You can try `onErrorResumeNext()` and conditionally switch to `Flowable.empty()` if the error indicates a close exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to close the stream successfully by creating my own operator and creating a `Flowable` from it.

This class is a new RxJava Operator that implements and logs the exception I get from closing an `InputStream`, which for my use case is alright.

```
public class MyFlowableOperator implements FlowableOperator {
  @Override
  public Subscriber apply(Subscriber subscriber) throws Exception {
    return new Subscriber() {
      @Override
      public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        subscriber.onSubscribe(s);
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(Object o) {
        subscriber.onNext(o);
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable t) {
        if(t instanceof SocketException) {
          log.debug("Input Stream Closed");
        } else {
          subscriber.onError(t);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onComplete() {
        subscriber.onComplete();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Below is how I declare a new Instance of the RxJava Operator and utilize it when creating the `Flowable` from the `InputStream`

```
// Private method to utilize the new RxJava Operator
private Subscriber getFlows(Subscriber subscriber) {
try {
    return new MyFlowableOperator().apply(subscriber);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
  }
  return null;
}
```

When creating the `Flowable` itself, I use the `lift` method to call my method and return a `Flowable` with error handling.

```
// Declaration of the Flowables
Flowable<byte[]> flowable = Bytes.from(inputStream)
                                 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                                 .distinct()
                                 .lift(this::getFlows);

Flowable<byte[]> flowable2 = Bytes.from(inputStream2)
                                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                                  .distinct()
                                  .lift(this::getFlows);
```